# What does "ATS climb gradient" mean?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, sid-star

[image]

On a Jeppesen SID chart, the climb gradient is not standard, because it's greater than 3.3%. What specifically does the ATS (7.4%) climb gradient mean?

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Above is the same SID, but from the official [chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxcI9.png) ([aerocivil.gov.co](http://www.aerocivil.gov.co/servicios-a-la-navegacion/servicio-de-informacion-aeronautica-ais/Documents/52%20SKVV.pdf)).

ATS means Air Traffic Services. That climb gradient is what the ATS requires. Versus PDG (procedure design gradients), the minimum to clear obstacles.

---

From the Colombian AIP [GEN 2.2 Abbreviations used in AIS publications](http://www.aerocivil.gov.co/servicios-a-la-navegacion/servicio-de-informacion-aeronautica-ais/Documents/15%20GEN%202.2.pdf):

- PDG = Gradiente del procedimiento de diseño
- ATS = Servicio de tránsito aéreo